# start MooTools Events Calendar next month

Tags: javascript, calendar, mootools

i'm using this calendar http://dansnetwork.com/mootools/events-calendar/usage/. I can't understand how can i start this calendar for next month, if current month is august, i want to start it for september.

What i've tried:

```
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = new Date(date.getMonth() +1 );
    var y = date.getFullYear();

 $('#calendar1').fullCalendar({
      editable: true,
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: new Date(y, m, 1)
```

but it does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source it doesn't seem like there is an option to explicitly set which month to show initially. There is however the `newDate` option which allows you to set the initial selected date, which I'm guessing would work as far as showing the month you want.

http://dansnetwork.com/mootools/events-calendar/source/  (line 22)